# GLM: invalid value encountered in log special.gammaln

Tags: distributions, python, generalized-linear-model, pattern-recognition

I've never used GLM before so I would like to have some hints on how to use it and if I'm missing any steps.

My challenge:
I want to know if the price of product is influenced, positively or negatively by other variables that I can measure:

- Production time of a machine that stays on to build the product during a day
- How much time it takes to build one single product in a day
- How much is the manpower cost per product in a day
- How many products are built in a day

I thought that using a GLM would help me understand this. However, I have two doubts:

1. Should I study the distribution of my variables before choosing the type of family of GLM?
2. I use Python to do the GLM but I get a warning:

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log   special.gammaln(n -
> y + 1) + y * np.log(mu / (1 - mu + 1e-20)) +
> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log   n * np.log(1 - mu +
> 1e-20)) * var_weights

But I don't understand what it means.

3. How should I interpret the results? When following tutorials, the coef were more interpretable than what I got (ex. 0.67)

[image: Results]

--- For reproducibility, here is the code I used ---

```
# creating the Numpy array 
array = np.array([[4, 441, 25, 4, 17], 
                  [10, 444, 49, 8, 9], 
                  [3, 483, 12, 2, 38],
                  [2,447,10,1,43],
                  [4,423,22,3,19],
                  [3,19,19,3,1],
                  [18,445,111,17,4],
                  [7,423,42,7,10],
                  [9,426,53,8,8],
                  [12,378,54,8,7],
                  [36,450,225,36,2],]) 
   
# creating a list of column names 
column_values = ['CONST', 'ACTUAL_PRODTIME', 'TIME_LOGO', 'COST_PPL_LOGO', 'LOGO'] 
  
# creating the dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame(data = array,   
                  columns = column_values) 

model = smf.glm(
                formula = "CONST ~ ACTUAL_PRODTIME + TIME_LOGO + COST_PPL_LOGO + LOGO",
                data = df, 
                family = sm.families.Binomial())
# Fit the model
result = model.fit()

# Display and interpret results
print(result.summary())
```

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Questions about code are off topic here, and your question may get closed. But there's also statistical issues in your question, so I am not voting to close.  If you rewrite it to emphasize the statistical aspects, that would be good.

Comment: Thank you! I edited it, let me know if that's not enough.

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: you could keep the data in the question. Family Binomial is for binary dependent variable or for a count variable with a given number of trials in each observation. So, Binomial is not the appropriate family. (I'm surprised that it does not raise an exception for invalid input)

Comment: @Josef I  edited so that the code is there to replicate the tests. How could I choose the right family? Can you point me to any resource that I could read?

Comment: you need a model or family for either non-negative integers or non-negative or positive continuous random variables. In the former case Poisson or Poisson quasi-maximum-likelihood should work. Otherwise, GLM in statsmodels has only Gamma and inverse gaussian as families for dependent variable in R+

Comment: statsmodels does not do enough input checking in this case. The results are just a "numerical accident" in how computations are performed and don't make much sense. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/9058

Comment: So in the future, I should first look at the nature of the variables (integers, continuous, etc) then probably have a look at their distribution (both independent and dependent or only the dependent variable?), and then decide which model or family to choose from. Apart from GLM, is there any other model that could help me?

Comment: The choice of model/family depends on only the dependent variable. statsmodels does not have models for R+, continuous, positive random variables outside of GLM (except count models when used as QMLE). A frequently used approach is to log or box-cox transform strictly positive dependent variables, but this correspond then to a different distribution, e.g. log-normal)

Answer (score 0):

Your data doesn't fit a binomial distribution. In `R` you would not be able to run this code, but `statsmodels` doesn't throw an error.

For a binomial GLM - you need to supply the $y$ data either as empirical ratios (when you divide the $y_i$'s by the number of experiments $m_i$'s), or as two columns - one with the number of successes, and another with the number of failures.